# Extract the closest adjacent indices to an index in a vector

Tags: r, vectorization

I have a vector of length `N`, and a random index `ind` in that vector.
I would like to extract the 11 closest indices, in the most symmetric way possible, to `ind` in the most efficient way, such as not to go beyond the length of the original vector, and also not get negative indices.

Examples:

if `N = 200`, and `ind = 199`, I would like to extract 190:200.

if `ind = 3`, the result should be 1:11.

if `ind = 195`, the result should be 190:200.

I can do it with `if` but seems to inefficient:

```
ff = function(ind, N){
  vv = sapply(ind, function(x) c((x-5):(x+5)))
  if (max(vv) > N) {
    vv = vv - max(vv) + N
  } else if (min(vv) < 6) {
    vv = vv - min(vv) + 1
  }
  return(vv)
}
```

Is there a more efficient way (e.g. subsetting) to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few approaches:

**1)** Using `order`

```
sort(head(order(abs(1:N - ind)), 11L))
```

**2)** Sort the absolute difference between indices and `ind` and then take the first 11 positions

```
sort((1:N)[as.integer(names(head(sort(abs(setNames(1:N, 1:N) - ind)), 11L)))])
```

**3)** Use radix sort:

```
sort(head(sort(abs(1:N - ind), index.return=TRUE)$ix, 11L))
```